# Character limit with just numbers in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

In a `<input type="number">` I have to limit the numbers that can be entered to 7. Moreover, on Chrome I am able to input just numbers, but not on Firefox or IE.

```
<input type="number" id="myInputNumber" name="myInputNumber" [pattern]="myPattern"
[(ngModel)]="myModel" maxlength="7"  #fooModel="ngModel">
```

I know that type number are not supported on Firefox, so there is a function that allows me to reach the goal on all three browsers?

Comment: hAvE yOu tRiEd AnYtHinG?

Comment: max=“9999999”.. ?

Comment: @MikeOne max only works for arrows to increase/decrease, not for user input

Comment: Ah right.. so I guess a directive might be needed to enforce that limit..

Answer (score 0):

`maxlength` is ignored on `type="number"` by design.

You'll have to implement a custom directive.
[Here's a tutorial](https://codeburst.io/digit-only-directive-in-angular-3db8a94d80c3) you can follow.